# Angular 4+ 3rd party module import 404 error with base tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am putting an angular portion into my MVC app.  As such, I have added a  tag to my layout view to find the Angular source code, and this is working great.

My issue arises in trying to add a 3rd party module to my project. I added it through the package.json with no problem, and added the module to my app.module.ts as follows:

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/fileupload';
```

The reference is found, Visual Studio is happy, everything is fine.  However, when I run the project locally, I get the following 404 error:

> GET http://localhost:59911/src/primeng/fileupload 404 (Not Found)

It seems to me likely that the  tag is causing the issue, but I can't remove it without killing the rest of the Angular functionality.  Any hints?  Can I add an override to the imports call?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: i think it should be like this @primeng/fileupload

Comment: @JaisAnkit OP's post is correct, see PrimeNG website https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that primeng was not in the mapping, so it was looking for it in src.

I added the following to systemjs.config.js:

- in maps:

  'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
- in packages:

  primeng: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

On PrimeNG's official website they suggested using `import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/fileupload';` but it doesn't work any more. I guess they didn't update the docs.

```
You need { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

The structure is [image]

In the `primeng.d.ts` file PrimeNG re-exported all modules.

`export * from './components/fileupload/fileupload';`

For now, no matter which PrimeNG module is used, it is all from `primeng/primeng`. Here's the imported modules in my project:

```
import {
  ButtonModule,
  CodeHighlighterModule,
  ConfirmDialogModule,
  FieldsetModule,
  FileUploadModule,
  GrowlModule,
  MessagesModule
} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

The version I use is  `"primeng": "^4.2.1"`

Comment: Good spot, but it seems to work with either.  I found the issue and posted below.

Comment: Will do, won't let me do it until tomorrow.